# changing position of Magento Left Col blocks

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, sidebar

I want to change the magento left column block. 
I have

- Compare products
- Community poll
- filtration
- My Cart

i want to change the order's to

- Filtration
- Compare products
- my cart
- community poll

My working website : http://m.machinetoolsemart.com/welding-machine/tig-welder.html

Can you guide  me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the chance you may send me a welder :)

You'll need to use **before=""** and **after=""**

Open up catalog.xml and find

You will see it has **before="cart_sidebar"** or **before="-"**, which means before the sidebar cart and before all.

So to change the order you will need to find the names of each block you want to be before or after and change it in the layout/.xml files.

e.g. Within poll.xml or possibly local.xml, depending on how the theme has been written, you would find the after="-", which means after everything else

```
<block type="poll/activePoll" name="left.poll" after="-">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried that keywords, But nothing happen. Still in same order. In my left column in catalog.xml file

Comment: <reference name="left">
<!-- Compare product -->  
            <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" after="-" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
<!-- Community poll -->               
            <block type="poll/activePoll" name="right.poll" after="-">
                <action method="setPollTemplate"><template>poll/active.phtml</template><type>poll</type></action>
                <action method="setPollTemplate"><template>poll/result.phtml</template><type>results</type></action>
            </block>
        </reference>

Comment: i can't find the filtration xml code what to do?

Comment: it's working, my working xml code: <reference name="left">
            <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
        </reference>